# Android: TextView margin bottom

Tags: android

I have an image with a square... In layout I want to set text inside square, so I set property margin bottom 100dp to 'TextView' and in HDPI phone my text is in square. That's cool. But when I run my app on MDPI device Text looks a little bit higher then it should be.

And its understandable, because MDPI and HDPI has different resolutions...So how to be ? How to set text so, that its looks proportional on both devices?

Comment: What units did you use to set the text size? The text size will be proportionally the same if you use dip (density independent pixels).

Comment: Text size ? We are not talking about text size....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap the image and the text inside a FrameLayout, and give the TextView a `layout_gravity="center"` attribute? With your current method, different aspect ratios will give you different positioning.

Comment: You're trying to overlay it onto a specific part of an image? In that case, you might want to just give the TextView a layout_gravity of `"top|left"`, a gravity of `"center"` and find the exact pixel x,y coordinates of the square, the size of the square in pixels, and give your TextView that width and height, and left and top margins to match the x and y coordinates, respectively.

Comment: Really though, there's probably a better way to do this. Please add more details. You can probably just leave the square off the image, and just give the TextView a background to match instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FrameLayout` in this case. Here is a simple example:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"            
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"            
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:text="This is text"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Ha, beat me to it. Good answer. :D

Comment: my image is 480 for 320 and square is not at the center of image

Comment: @Jim, please update your question with this detail. Also add screenshot of what you want vs. what you see.